# Unable to Install Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, pip

Tried running the following command on the directory where I activated my virtual environment :

```
pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy
```

The error message received is :

> "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask-SQLAlchemy (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for Flask-SQLAlchemy"

Does anyone face similar problem?

Comment: It installs by `pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy` with no error on windows 8, Python 3.8 virtual environment. Have you tried to install something else? You may have problem with pip?

Comment: Can you try `python3 -m pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy`. If your python is 3.8 you may try `python3.8 -m pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten this error.  I think I resolved it by upgrading pip.  Try:

pip install pip==21.0.1